# OpenSSL Differentiating Trusted CA Certificates From Self-Signed Ones

Tags: c++, authentication, openssl, cryptography

I'm currently working on an authentication plugin for an existing application. According to the protocol, the plugin shall allow the certificates that are signed **only by a trusted CA**. All self-signed certificates are supposed to be accepted as invalid. I generated a self-signed certificate, also have a certificate that is signed by a trusted authority, too. I also implemented two different functions that validates self-signed certificates and trusted certificates for test purposes.

My problem is, the function that is supposed to validate the trusted certificates does also validate my self-signed certificate. Below you can see my implementation:

```
FILE* certificate_file = fopen("cert.cer", "r");
X509* certificate = PEM_read_X509(certificate_file, NULL, NULL, NULL);

X509_STORE* store = X509_STORE_new();
X509_STORE_CTX* ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();

X509_STORE_add_cert(store, certificate);
X509_SORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, certificate, NULL);

X509_verify_cert(ctx);
```

What am I missing? Some say about **certificate chains**, but in most of the examples the parameter is just *NULL*. There are some other implementations but they are either too complex or not really answering my question.

To avoid any misunderstanding, I want this function to return invalid when a self-signed certificate is given as the input.

Comment: Is running the openssl binary programatically an option for you? everything you need is possible from the command line.

Comment: Then I guess we are able to pass the shell commands into some of the functions? I'm not sure just yet, since I am at the very beginning of the plugin but seems like an option for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be missing is the concept of a trusted certificate store. A trusted store contains the certificates you *explicitly* trust. Now if you create one with just root certificates (e.g. taken from a browser's trust store) only the chain with the intermediate CA certificate and your own certificate will be trusted. As your self signed certificate isn't in the trust store it would not be trusted, as the chain is only 1 certificate in size and it doesn't lead back to the trust store.

So you would be maintaining two trust stores: one for your test environment with the self signed certificate and one for your actual deployment with the root or intermediate CA certificate to validate your end user certificate.

Comment: I believe there is a slight misunderstanding here. I don't want my self-signed certificate to be accepted as valid. I want my function to return invalid when a self-signed certificate is given. However, this function returns valid when I use my self-signed certificate.

Comment: I don't see the misunderstanding. If you don't want to validate your self signed certificate as valid then don't add it to a trust store. When validating a certificate chain, you **must** verify that one of the certificates in the chain is part of a specific trust store (i.e. a certificate store containing only certificates you explicitly trust). I think you may be missing that last step.

Comment: I see, you suggest that I remove "X509_STORE_add_cert(store, certificate)" part. It actually returns invalid in that case. I guess all I need to do now is to find a way of adding the trusted certificates into the store.

Comment: Normally you create a (PKCS#12) store on disk and load it instead of creating it inside your code. Then you use the CLI tools to maintain the store. If you just want to trust one CA root certificate then your store just contains that one (until a new CA root certificate is issued when the previous one is about to expire or is revoked).

Comment: Is this a common approach for the client-server systems? The thing I hesitate is, this plugin will be used in a peer-2-peer system. Since there is no application server, is storing in each client still a valid approach?

Comment: Well yes, quite common. The other option is to use different methods of authentication. One common method is PGP with a web of trust. Explaining all the possibilities of PKI requires just a bit more space than available here though. Key management is tough.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me out. Unfortunately the protocol I'm implementing does not involve PGP. I guess I'll prepare a team meeting to discuss our options.